# How to convert elements of Array{Any,1} to Array{Int64,1}

Tags: julia

Suppose I have an array having integers and arrays of integers combined. Which means that it is an `Array{Any,1}`. I want to convert this `Array{Any,1}` to an array of `Array{Int64,1}`. How do I go about this?

```
gh = [12,23,34,[10,11,12,13,14],[20,21,22], [30,25]]
```

I expect to get

```
13-element Array{Int64,1}:
12
23
34
10
11
12
13
14
20
21
22
30
25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
collect(Iterators.flatten(gh))
```

does just what you want.